# 2D Array (Arrays of Arrays) Minesweeper

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to the forums, so I'd like to apologise if this doesn't follow the standards of the site, however I have a question about a 2D Array Minesweeper program.

I am trying to place mines randomly upon the board, which is built via arrays. Unfortunately, the mines are being placed randomly on a diagonal, rather than the whole board. My code for the MineField is:

```
    public MineField(int w, int h, int m)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    mineField = new State[w][h];
    surroundingMines = new int[w][h];
    initialiseMineField = new int[w][h];
    traceOn = true; //set to false before submitting
    width = w;
    height = h;
    mineCount = m;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            mineField[i][j] = State.COVERED;
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    {
        int randomNumber = r.nextInt(m);
        int a = randomNumber;
        int b = randomNumber;
        mineField[a][b] = State.MINED;
    }

}
```

This is giving me the output of (Randomized each time, but only along that diagonal line):

   `0  1  2  3  4
0| .  .  .  .  . 
1| .  *  .  .  . 
2| .  .  *  .  . 
3| .  .  .  *  . 
4| .  .  .  .  .`

How can I stop it going on that diagonal, and how can I stop the mines from overlapping? Thanks!

Comment: you're setting `a` and `b` to the same value... that will always be a diagonal.

Comment: Jesus, how did I not notice that! Thank you.

Comment: Because when you get familiar with a codeline, you stop noticing small details. Like you ignore a `;` at the end of an if statement or something similar. Then when you spend an hour and a half of debugging trying to work out why your if isn't working someone comes up behind and says 'You know you have a semicolon after your if right?", at which point you punch out your monitor and ragequit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I stop it from going on the diagonal?

Generate two random numbers for the two coordinates, instead of using one random number for both.

```
for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
{
    mineField[r.nextInt(w)][r.nextInt(h)] = State.MINED;
}
```

#### How can I stop the mines from overlapping?

Two possible approaches.

1. Generate, check if already a mine, and if so, retry. Do this inside the loop so that you do not increment your `k` until you have successfully generated a unique mine.
2. Make a list of all possible locations (as row-column pairs), do a random permutation of the list, and take the first `m` pairs to be mines.

Here is some sample code for approach 1.

```
for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
{
    while (true) {
       int a = r.nextInt(w);
       int b = r.nextInt(h);
       if (mineField[a][b] != State.MINED) { // We have discovered an un-mined location.
           mineField[a][b] = State.MINED;
           break; // get out of the while loop.
       }
    }
}
```

I'll leave approach 2 as an exercise for the OP.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `[r.nextInt(h)][r.nextInt(w)]` to accommodate for non-square shapes?

Comment: @Obicere, Yes, it should. Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that's certainly fixed my diagonal issue and cleaned up some code.

Comment: @Halt, You are very welcome. Please remember you can mark this as the accepted answer if it resolves your question. :)

Comment: Okay, so I'm having a bit of a block. I know I require an if - else. If it has been mined, I want the loop to go through again and place the mine elsewhere, otherwise I want it to place the mine there. But I'm lost for how to do it.

Comment: @Halt, Use a `while` loop inside the `for` loop which will keep picking until you have found a location that is not already mined. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Halt, Answer has been updated. I agree that this idiom is a little non-obvious if you have not seen it before.

Comment: @Merlin, It's sort of working. If I set my mines to 5, it will display five mines randomly, without overlapping. However if I set mines to say, 10, it will display 8.

Comment: @Halt, I have been assuming that `State` is an `enum`, but if it is not then `==` will not work correctly for comparison. I would recommend [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and posting more of the relevant code.

Comment: It is certainly an enum. I will do so, though I find it difficult placing the correct code within a question as I don't want to overload anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a & b to the same number. For example, lets say your variable randomNumber = 1, you then set a & b to randomNumber. You then are placing the mines at [1,1] and so on giving you mines only on the diagonal. This can be solved by adding another randomNumber variable so that a & b both have their own separate random integer.